# Ruby Beginner - Accessing Another Class Object

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a simple turn-based battle in Ruby, but I keep getting stuck when it comes to classes. I tried to do this by starting with basic code and building it up around that. I was able to make it work simply enough by using regular variables and basic attack code:

```
player = "goodguy"
player_health = 15
player_damage = 5

enemy = "badguy"
enemy_health = 15
enemy_damage = 5

puts "#{player} attacks #{enemy} and does #{player_damage} damage."
enemy_health -= player_damage
puts "#{enemy} has #{enemy_health} remaining."
```

Then, I turned the attack into a function (I had to make the variables global so the function could see them):

```
$player = "goodguy"
$player_health = 15
$player_damage = 5

$enemy = "badguy"
$enemy_health = 15
$enemy_damage = 5

def player_attack
  puts "#{$player} attacks #{$enemy} and does #{$player_damage} damage."
  $enemy_health -= $player_damage
  puts "#{$enemy} has #{$enemy_health} health remaining."
  if $enemy_health <= 0
    puts "#{$enemy} died!"
  end    
end    

player_attack()
```

Next, I turned `Player` into a class:

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :name; :hp; :damage
  def initialize(name, hp, damage)
    @name = name
    @hp = hp
    @damage = damage
  end

  def attack
    puts "#{self.name} attacks #{$enemy}!"
    $enemy_health -= @damage
    puts $enemy_health
  end
end

$enemy = "badguy"
$enemy_health = 15
$enemy_damage = 5    

me = Player.new("goodguy", 15, 5)

me.attack
```

This is where I get stuck. When I turn `Enemy` into a class (basically modeled exactly after the `Player` class), I can't figure out how to make the two objects interact with each other. This code doesn't work, but here's the last of what I tried. The `#{}` variables are more to show what I'm trying to make happen than anything else:

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :name; :hp; :damage
  def initialize(name, hp, damage)
    @name = name
    @hp = hp
    @damage = damage
  end

  def attack
    puts "#{self.name} attacks #{badguy.name}!"
    badguy.hp -= @damage
    puts badguy.hp
  end
end

class Enemy
  attr_accessor :name; :hp; :damage
  def initialize(name, hp, damage)
    @name = name
    @hp = hp
    @damage = damage
  end

  def attack
    puts "#{self.name} attacks #{goodguy.name}!"
    player.hp -= @damage
    puts player.hp
  end
end  

goodguy = Player.new("Nicehero", 15, 5)
badguy = Enemy.new("Eviljerk", 15, 5)

me.attack
```

Basically, what I want to do is make it so that the `Player` object can interact with the `Enemy` object. I can't seem to get this working when I try to make 2 classes interact with each other; Also, the #{variable.name} isn't the only thing I've tried for getting the functions to report those values, but I can't seem to find how to actually reference that object.

Obviously there's something I'm missing about how objects interact or what my code is doing vs what I think it should be doing. I would appreciate any suggestions on getting these two classes to interact or how this should be rewritten so that it functions as intended.

Comment: The classes don't magically know about instances of each other; some entity has to tell them.  A common approach is to have another class that represents the Game or the Board and that is responsible for saying to, say, the Player, "it is your turn, here is the enemy, here's what the enemy did, what will you do?"

Comment: Thanks @JacobM, can you give an example of how this would be done with a parent class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As alluded to by @JacobM, the problem you are encountering has to do with the inability of your classes to know about other instances of each other without you explicitly passing them as an argument. Although your initial workaround of using **global variables** to hold references to the enemy and the player will work, this practice is strongly discouraged because it "leaks" the logic of your program throughout the entire body of your game, which is generally undesirable (see [Global Variables are Bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) for a detailed explanation of why to avoid them).

By removing the `$` from your code, `player` becomes a local variable when defined in the `attack` method:

```
def attack
  puts "#{self.name} attacks #{goodguy.name}!"
  player.hp -= @damage
  puts player.hp
end
```

In this construction, the `player` variable that you want to reference as an instance of the `Player` class is actually an undefined local variable that you have declared within the method body. Because the code of your `Player` and `Enemy` classes is the same, I would recommend that you create a *superclass* to hold this logic:

```
class Piece
  attr_accessor :name, :hp, :damage
  def initialize(name, hp, damage)
    @name = name
    @hp = hp
    @damage = damage
  end

  def attack(opponent)
    opponent.hp -= @damage
    puts "#{@name} attacks #{opponent.name}!"
    puts "#{opponent.name}'s HP: #{opponent.hp}"
  end
end
```

and then create *subclasses* for the `Player` and the `Enemy`:

```
class Player < Piece
end

class Enemy < Piece
end
```

With this construction, you can create any number of enemies and pieces and have them all interact with each other separately:

```
> hero = Player.new("Zeus", 1000, 100)
=> #<Player:0x007fbd33958498 @name="Zeus", @hp=1000, @damage=100> 
> goul = Enemy.new("Pariah", 400, 50)
=> #<Enemy:0x007fbd33949b78 @name="Pariah", @hp=400, @damage=50>
> ghost = Enemy.new("Bane", 600, 75)
=> #<Enemy:0x007fbd33937680 @name="Bane", @hp=600, @damage=75> 


> hero.attack(goul)
Zeus attacks Pariah!
Pariah's HP: 300
=> nil
```

Answer (score 4):

As all of the code of `Player` and `Enemy` is same, I can model them in a parent class (giving it a dumb name `Man`, you can give it some fancy name :D) removing all the code duplicity, and than inheriting from the common class.

There can be various ways to interact between two objects. I have taken the simplest by passing the other object in `attack` function and start interacting with it.

I will change this code in following way:

```
class Man
    attr_accessor :name, :hp, :damage
    def initialize(name, hp, damage)
        @name = name
        @hp = hp
        @damage = damage
    end

    def attack opposite_team_man
        puts "#{self.name} attacks #{opposite_team_man.name}!"
        opposite_team_man.hp -= @damage
        puts opposite_team_man.hp
    end

end
class Player < Man
end

class Enemy < Man
end  

goodguy = Player.new("Nicehero", 15, 5)
badguy = Enemy.new("Eviljerk", 15, 5)

goodguy.attack badguy
```

Comment: The `puts "#{self.name} attacks #{opposite_team_man.name}!"` is working, but then I get a `undefined method 'hp' for #<Enemy:0x14a2f8 @hp=15, @name="Eviljerk", @damage=5> (NoMethodError)` when I try to run this. Any idea why?

Comment: Ahhh, because, this should be `attr_accessor :name, :hp, :damage`, Updated the answer.

Comment: Oops! I was using `;` and not `,` in mine ... that makes sense and it works exactly like I wanted it to. Thanks for your help!